# Browsers can not open the HTML from HDD (ebook)

Tags: permissions, xubuntu, firefox, html, ebooks

I am using Xubuntu 14.04, Firefox 49.0.2.

Since I started using Xubuntu 14.04 I have a problem with HTML files on HDD. 
I did not have that problem with Xubuntu/Ubuntu 12.04.
When I try to open the HTML (e-book) file from hard disk drive

> home/admin/Documents/Polaris SF CD vol 2/index.html

with any browser (eg.Firefoks, Chrome, Midori) it always says eg.:

> File not found.
> Firefox can not find the file at / home / admin / Documents / Polaris SF CD vol 2 /html/a1.html
> Firefox can’t find the file at /home/admin/Documents/Polaris SF CD vol 2/html/menu.html.

But when I loading a copy of ebook from USB there is no problem.
Path is: `file://localhost/media/admin/Zagor/Home/Polaris%20SF%20CD%20vol%202/index.html`

I tried different versions to open file from HDD:

`localhost/home/admin/Documents/Polaris%20SF%20CD%20vol%202/index.html`
`file://home/admin/Documents/Polaris%20SF%20CD%20vol%202/index.html`
`file:///home/admin/Documents/Polaris%20SF%20CD%20vol%202/index.html`
`file:///home/admin/Documents/Polaris SF CD vol 2/index.html`
... it's not working.

Then I tried to correct Firefox file, like on this [website](http://xubuntugeek.blogspot.rs/2015/03/solved-firefox-opens-blank-pages-intead.html)(whit mousepad and sudo premissions, of course),but there is no change.
Any idea what the problem is?

Just to mention that when I save a page from the Internet (with Firefox), there are no such problems.

`ls -a "/home/admin/Documents/Polaris SF CD vol 2" 
. AUTORUN COPYRIGH.TXT HTML index.html README.TXT 
.. AUTORUN.INF GRAPHICS IMAGES next.gif STYLE`

`ls -a "/home/admin/Documents/Polaris SF CD vol 2/HTML/a1.html"
 /home/admin/Documents/Polaris SF CD vol 2/HTML/a1.html`

I tyed to removing the spaces by changing the directory name to PolarisSFCDvol2 and right click on the file index.html in my file manager (Thunar) and choose "open with Firefox Web browser", but No Results.

Comment: what is the output of `ls -a / home / admin / Documents / Polaris SF CD vol 2 /html/a1.html`

Comment: ls -a /home/admin/Documents/Polaris SF CD vol 2/HTML/a1.html
ls: cannot access /home/admin/Documents/Polaris: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access SF: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access CD: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access vol: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 2/HTML/a1.html: No such file or directory

Comment: But the file and folder are exist.  The start file  (home page) is  "/home/admin/Documents/Polaris SF CD vol 2/index.html"

Comment: ls -a "/home/admin/Documents/Polaris SF CD vol 2/HTML/a1.html" /home/admin/Documents/Polaris SF CD vol 2/HTML/a1.html

Answer (score 0):

The spaces in one of the directory names is breaking things for you. USB copy has the spaces replaced with %20. You can Either rename the directory removing the spaces By Changing the Directory name to PolarisSFCDvol2 or the easiest solution is to right click on the file in your file manager (Nautilus suggested) and choose "open with Firefox Web browser"

Comment: ls -a "/home/milan/Documents/Polaris SF CD vol 2"
.   AUTORUN      COPYRIGH.TXT  HTML    index.html  README.TXT
..  AUTORUN.INF  GRAPHICS      IMAGES  next.gif    STYLE

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I meant ls -la "/home/milan/Documents/Polaris SF CD vol 2/html/a1.html" and [edit] the result into your question.